# Error when build catkin during lanelet2 installation?

Tags: ros

```
sheraz@sheraz-HP-EliteBook-850-G6:~$ cd catkin_ws
sheraz@sheraz-HP-EliteBook-850-G6:~/catkin_ws$ catkin build
--------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:          [cached] /opt/ros/melodic
Workspace:                   /home/sheraz/catkin_ws
--------------------------------------------------------------
Build Space:        [exists] /home/sheraz/catkin_ws/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/sheraz/catkin_ws/devel
Install Space:      [unused] /home/sheraz/catkin_ws/install
Log Space:          [exists] /home/sheraz/catkin_ws/logs
Source Space:       [exists] /home/sheraz/catkin_ws/src
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
--------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        None
--------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
--------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
--------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.
--------------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '11' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                    
[build] Package table is up to date.                                           
Starting  >>> lanelet2_core                                                    
_______________________________________________________________________________
Errors     << lanelet2_core:check /home/sheraz/catkin_ws/logs/lanelet2_core/build.check.017.log
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.17", but
  required is at least "3.6" (found /usr/bin/python2)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:376 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPythonInterp.cmake:152 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/python.cmake:4 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:164 (include)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/mrt_cmake_modules/cmake/mrt_cmake_modules-macros.cmake:83 (find_package)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/mrt_cmake_modules/cmake/mrt_cmake_modules-extras.cmake:26 (include)
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/mrt_cmake_modules/cmake/mrt_cmake_modulesConfig.cmake:222 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
cd /home/sheraz/catkin_ws/build/lanelet2_core; catkin build --get-env lanelet2_core | catkin env -si  /usr/bin/make cmake_check_build_system; cd -
...............................................................................
Failed     << lanelet2_core:check                   [ Exited with code 2 ]     
Failed    <<< lanelet2_core                         [ 0.1 seconds ]            
Abandoned <<< lanelet2                              [ Unrelated job failed ]   
Abandoned <<< lanelet2_io                           [ Unrelated job failed ]   
Abandoned <<< lanelet2_maps                         [ Unrelated job failed ]   
Abandoned <<< lanelet2_projection                   [ Unrelated job failed ]   
Abandoned <<< lanelet2_traffic_rules                [ Unrelated job failed ]   
Abandoned <<< lanelet2_matching                     [ Unrelated job failed ]   
Abandoned <<< lanelet2_routing                      [ Unrelated job failed ]   
Abandoned <<< lanelet2_python                       [ Unrelated job failed ]   
Abandoned <<< lanelet2_examples                     [ Unrelated job failed ]   
Abandoned <<< lanelet2_validation                   [ Unrelated job failed ]   
[build] Summary: 0 of 11 packages succeeded.                                   
[build]   Ignored:   None.                                                     
[build]   Warnings:  None.                                                     
[build]   Abandoned: 10 packages were abandoned.                               
[build]   Failed:    1 packages failed.                                        
[build] Runtime: 0.1 seconds total.
```

Comment: In the future, please [format your output properly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). I fixed it for you. Don't make us do that -- that's part of asking a good question.

Comment: `Could NOT find PythonInterp: Found unsuitable version "2.7.17", but required is at least "3.6" (found /usr/bin/python2)`. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1473294/edit) to clearly show us the release of Ubuntu that you are running, and the version(s) of Python3 you have installed.